# Turn on Lightning experience on Developer edition Org?

Tags: lightning-experience, lightning

Is there a way to turn on the **Lightning experience** (Not components) on a free Developer edition Org ?
Or is it only works on Sandboxes now?

Comment: Lightning Component are turned On - Im talking about Lightning Expirience.

Comment: Apologies!  My mistake.

Answer (score 2):

[Check out this link.](https://www.salesforce.com/blog/2015/08/future-of-crm-salesforce-lightning.html)

Lightning will become instantly available October 17th with the release of Winter ‘16

There is a pilot program where you can request pre-release access using [this link](https://www.salesforce.com/form/signup/lightning-ee-signup.jsp).

Comment: Thanks..I guess I will have to wait a bit more for that :)

Comment: Yes, or Try pre-rerelease access to get an idea. (Accept answer if you got what you are looking for  :)